# Eclipse commands in java code

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Is it possible to run eclipse commands through Java code? 
For example, I would like to write a Eclipse plug-in (Eclipse project) that deletes other Eclipse projects that have a given name. In Eclipse, to delete a project, we right click and click 'Delete'. Is there a way to do this through code.

Comment: You mean you want to write eclipse plugin ?

Comment: yes writing a plugin

Comment: You're trying to find out whether a program can destroy itself?

Comment: Not destroy itself but delete other Eclipse projects on the workspace

Comment: yes it is possible. eclipse is completely written in java. you can go to http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Foverview-summary.html and refer the api

Comment: Here is a tutorial that will teach you how to write an eclipse plugin.

http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a project in the workspace you find the `IProject` object for the project and then call `delete`:

```
IProject project = ... get project

project.delete(true, false, progress monitor);
```

One way to find the project is:

```
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();

IProject project = root.getProject("project name");
```